# Switch video element in Chromecast CAF Receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, caf-receiver-sdk

I want to implement a custom CAF receiver that does the following:

1. Plays a pre-roll ad video using an external ad SDK.
2. Plays a DASH or HLS live stream.

The features work fine on their own. It is when I am playing a live stream after an ad that the player throws this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
    at Hh.fk (http://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js:149:315)
    at yc (http://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js:30:291)
    at SourceBuffer.vc (http://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js:31:343)
    at SourceBuffer.b (http://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js:28:245)
```

This error is then followed by:

```
[cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104
```

Error 104 indicates that the source is not supported by the player, but since the streams play fine without an ad, this cannot be the issue. It is most likely a side effect caused by the SourceBuffer error above.

I am certain that the cause of the error is with the `video` element that the Ad SDK used to display the pre-roll video. The Ad SDK adds the element, plays the ad, and removes the element afterwards.

I've tried the following:

1. Set the `video` element inside the `cast-media-player` as the current playback element via `context.getPlayerManager().setMediaElement(...)` after the ad playback finished.
2. Created the `cast-media-player` after the ad finished and added it to the body. Then requested the stream playback.
3. A combination of 2→1: created the element and then set its video element as the current media element.

None of the above did work.

Is there a way to reset or re-init the player to use the `cast-media-player` element?

Note, that the ad-stitching supported by the CAF receiver is out of scope because the external ad SDK is a hard requirement.

Comment: Have you checked [this github post](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/issues/227) if you have encountered the same problem?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 it seems similar, but the CAF API does not expose a reset method or a way to re-initialize the whole player.